# Get-WinEvent Select time and field within data item of 1

Tags: powershell, events, logging

I am trying to view all events in 7045 where i am able to extract path name. However I want to select the timestamp of the event as well?

```
Get-WinEvent -Path ".\System.evtx" |
  where {$_.id -eq "7045"} |
    Foreach {([xml]$_.ToXml()).GetElementsByTagName("Data").itemOf(1)} |
      Select -ExpandProperty "#text" -Unique

Get-WinEvent -Path ".\System.evtx" |
  where {$_.id -eq "7045"} |
    Foreach {([xml]$_.ToXml()).GetElementsByTagName("Data").itemOf(1)} | 
      Select -ExpandProperty "#text" -Unique

Get-WinEvent -Path ".\System.evtx" |
  where {$_.id -eq "7045"} |
    Foreach {([xml]$_.ToXml()).GetElementsByTagName("Data").itemOf(0)} |
      Select -ExpandProperty "#text" -Unique
```

i want to get the output TimeCreated, Service Name, Service Path

At moment with 2 queries i can get the service name & then the service path?

Answer (score 3):

This might do it:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='System'; ID=7045} |
    Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, 
                            @{Label='Service Name'; Expression={$_.properties[0].Value}}, 
                            @{Label='Service Path'; Expression={$_.properties[1].Value}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and that's really helpful!